# Why GWT URL doesn't change on an event or a service call?

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I have two questions:

**Q: 1**

I'm currently developing a GWT app. The entry point for the app is: ImageViewer.java. I could well access it by http://127.0.0.1:8888/ImageViewer.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997. I have a service called "Search" which has corresponding "Async" and "Impl"'s defined. Now, I call the service from client side, using RPC. I could call the service, obtain return value. Everything works fine.

However, I expect the application to show a behavioral change on URL. i.e. when a service is being accessed, I thought it would be reflected on the browser's URL something like: http://127.0.0.1:8888/search?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 as I've modified web.xml. However, this behavior is not realized. Any particular reason why this is not reflected??

**Q:2**

This one is a reverse of the  previous ques. i.e. I have an application running. Let's say it has an entrypoint class(Imageviewer.java) and another composite class (searchClass.java) which would be loaded on the Imageviewer based on an event. This searchClass invokes the "search" service mentioned in the previous question.

I could load the "searchClass" in "Imageviewer", invoke the service, and the service also returns the value needed. Everything works fine... But,

I need something like this: by just typing this query string:

http://127.0.0.1:8888/search?value=John

I want the "searchClass" to be loaded on the "ImageViewer", call the service using the value(which is "john" in this case) and display the result. Is this possible at all?

**what I've tried:** I have tried to create a httpServletClass on the server and mapped it with the URL and could do the search. The search returns appropriate results. However, I want the results from the server to be displayed on the client. Remember, I'm directly using a servlet to read the URL and so there is no value being passed from client to server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. RPC (AJAX) calls are done Via [XHR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)  and do not change the browser URL.
2. You can't (with the URL you presented). GWT apps normally run in one web page, i.e. the URL does not change (see how gmail changes browser url bar). What you can do is enable [GWT history support](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html). Then your url would be http://host/#search?value=queryu

Comment: hi Peter, GWT History support link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

**A: 1.** To change URL, the hash part, you need to set new history token in the [History](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/History.html) class. More about history management in [this article](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html).

**A: 2.** For the second part you could achieve it by changing the history token, for instance "http://127.0.0.1/search#value=John". The history service will trigger an event if the # part changes. You could also use the part with "?", as in your example, if you use [Window.Location](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html) , but it will cause reload of the application, which would put the whole idea of using GWT in question.